# how to change selecting way of wpf datagrid cells on drag?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

When I drag the selected `DataGridCell` to next column cell, the entire cells of that particular columns not selecting. Selected cell and next column cell only selected. I want to select total column of selected cells.

My `DataGrid` selection vs `Outlook` -

[image]